# server on Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I have been trying to create an active directory for my environment. So I chose Microsoft Azure.  I have been able to create the users to the directory and also created a VM of windows server 2012 now what I want is that the systems[Attached here is the snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEm6y.jpg) in the organization can directly connect to the domain that I have provided in Microsoft Azure. kindly help me out on this or provide me with a link that can help me out

Answer (score 0):

You should change your other VMs' DNS to the Active Directory internal IP address.
[image]

Then you can change Virtual network DNS settings to that AD internal IP address, new created VMs DNS will be that internal IP address.
[image]

**Note:**

After change VM's DNS settings, you will lost connect to this VM, just use Azure portal to restart it, you will able to connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a hybrid setup, then DNS Servers need to be defined in the Virtual Network settings. If you want to resolve DNS across your machines, then update the virtual network DNS server addresses pointing to your domain controller static assigned IP address. All virtual machines will pick up the DNS server addresses from the virtual network as the virtual network interfaces for each virtual machine will be part of the virtual network.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34729730)